# Saving File Dialog / Prompt with Watir in Ruby

Tags: ruby, firefox, scripting, watir, win32ole

I'm using Watir to perform some actions on a website and eventually provide me with a prompt to save some file. What I would like to do is to follow the prompt automatically and have the file saved automatically as well.

From what I've seen, using win32ole has some functionality to perform these actions. I've successfully installed the gem via

```
gem install win32ole-pp
```

and requiring the win32ole gives no problem. However, when I call say

```
ai = WIN32OLE.new("AutoItX3.Control")
```

I receive the error that:

```
unknown OLE server: `AutoItX3.Control'
```

There is a proposed solution to this problem [here](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/FAQ#FAQ-HowdoIfixaWIN32OLERuntimeErrorwhenIuseAutoIt?), however the .dll in question is not located in the proper folder.

So, I'm just wondering either is there another way to do this in Watir? Or does there exist some other solution for the problem I am encountering?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you run a windows search for the `AutoItX3.dll` file? The file might not be exactly where they say in the FAQ. Could be worth a shot and try out the `regsvr32` command once you find it.

Comment: Yes I have, it did not come up unfortunately. Thanks for the thought though.

Comment: Strange. How about downloading the Zip file from here: http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/ (halfway down the page), the DLL is in that package and you can use that. Also if you're on Win7 perhaps have a look here (need to run as Admin): http://rubywithwatir.blogspot.com/2008/06/unknown-ole-server-autoitx3control.html

Comment: Ah fantastic, thank you Casper that seemed to do the trick. Now, I just need to find a good example of how to use AutoIt to manipulate the save file dialog box. All the examples I found seem to simply consist of code and have no relation to a real example so it makes it difficult to know what I would have to alter for my specific situation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with watir and firefox. Firefox have an option to automatically save targeted file types, regarding their MIME, without prompting in the parametrized folder. Watir have access to firefox parameters and can modify them :

```
downloadDir = "your-dl-dir"
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['browser.download.dir'] = downloadDir
profile['browser.download.folderList'] = 2
profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = 'images/jpeg, application/pdf, application/octet-stream'
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:firefox, :profile => profile)
```

source : http://elementalselenium.com/tips/2-download-a-file